# How to effectively cache cargo/Rust projects in an Azure Build Pipeline

Tags: caching, rust, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, rust-cargo

I have a set of Azure Build Pipelines that compile rust projects and currently use blob storage to store the `.cargo` and `target` folders as a cache.

When compiling locally, once a binary is compiled the first time, subsequent `cargo build`'s don't compile the dependent libraries/crates again, just the local binary, however with my current pipeline system, after downloading the cache and using the correct target folder to build into, the pipeline still downloads and builds crates.

This is my config.toml for the cache and any pipeline builds.

```
[build]
target-dir = "./target"
dep-info-basedir = "."
incremental = true
```

It has reduced compilation times in some cases but not nearly as much as I expect.
Can I cache more folders to increase speed? Is there some cache identifier that cargo is checking and fouling the cache over?

The pipelines run a custom xtask binary which performs many tasks including running `cargo build --release` could this be causing issues?

Comment: (I wonder if what you want isn't more easily achieved by using sccache with blob storage. (I thought that `~/.cargo/registry` and `target` would be sufficient…))

Comment: check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#ccache-cc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cache `target` and `~/.cargo/registry` as mentioned by Caesar in the comments above.

The following worked for me ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops)):

```
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: '"cargo" | "$(Agent.OS)" | Cargo.lock'
    path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\target
  displayName: cache cargo build

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: '"cargo-registry" | "$(Agent.OS)" | Cargo.lock'
    path: $(UserProfile)\.cargo\registry
  displayName: cache cargo registry
```

Comment: `$(UserProfile)` presumably only works on a Windows agent. Any idea what macro to use there for non-Windows build agents?

Comment: Probably right, I would assume what you need is `$(HOME)` (I did not test that though)